# How to make Froyo's portable hotspot more stable?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, htc-desire, wifi-hotspot

I have updated to Froyo on my HTC Desire yesterday and am testing out the portable hotspot option. The problem is that it is very unstable, at random times (1 to 10 minutes) I lose the WiFi connection.

I have a laptop on my lap and the Desire in my pocket, so it's not like they are out of reach. Does anybody have any ideas on this? Similar experiences?

Comment: What Froyo build did you install? I installed 4 as they came out and recently went with a Cyanogen Beta.

Comment: I use the stock build from HTC the came in during the OTA update. Never tried any other build.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than putting it in your pocket, place it next to your laptop with the screen on. Then you can see if your hotspot is cutting out, or maybe your 3G is cutting out. I imagine there is a threshold of where you need a certain strength of 3G signal to operate a hotspot.

Comment: Good suggestion! I have tried that, the 3G connection is stable all the time...